# "SEO" in a question, should it be removed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677060/segue-from-anywhere-to-the-first-scene-after-applicationdidbecomeactive) just came up in my review queue, and I noticed it has this section at the bottom:

> Some other phrases for Google: Always return to first scene on launch. Return to first scene when launched.

It was in my review queue for [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24677060/2).  I had planned to "improve" the edit by removing this but it was already accepted by the time I read the question.

This kind of stuff should just be removed, right?  I believe the question would still be quite discoverable on Google without it.

Comment: What I find important is that the question is still as good to discover as it would be with it. Since the main gateways to the stackexchange network are search engines I'd - generally speaking - regard SEO as useful and legitimate if it does not hurt the question too much.

Comment: @Perseids Other than choosing good tags, writing a good title, and writing a clear question (all of which one should be doing anyway), the SEO should be left to Stack Exchange (and, considering the search results I see on a daily basis, I think they've got it covered).

Comment: @jadarnel27 I mostly agree with you, and I was mainly thinking about edits whose summary mention SEO as motivation but otherwise follow the guidelines you have set. I also have some content edits in mind that would benefit discoverability without really changing the meaning of the question, but have no examples at hand. I'll come back here if I find any.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes, those extra search phrases are as useless as "Thanks!" at the end (or the *'Cheers.'* that the OP also had).

It's superfluous fluff, so remove it. Or not, I've already done it. BAM!!

Comment: "It's superfluous fluff... BAM!!".  Irony?

Comment: Since I had to look it up, I thought I would add this.  SEO == Search Engine Optimization

Comment: @adamdc78 There's never any irony on Meta. Ever.

Comment: @jmstoker wow,SEO has become such a buzzword in the last years that's astonishing to see someone, on the internet, that doesn't know what it stands for. Note to self: spend less time on the internet.

Comment: a pessimist is never disappointed if you delete it

Comment: @Srikanth "if you delete it" may be removed from your statement and it remains just as accurate.  So where is the specific application here?

Comment: "Pessimists are never disappointed" is never accurate. No matter how low a pessimist sets their expectations, the universe will find a way to let them down.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Please don't make assumptions about what other people know or don't know.  A lot of people spend lots of time on the Internet but perhaps don't visit the same kinds of sites you do or read the same kinds of articles.  (I didn't find out what SEO meant until late last year.)

Comment: @corsiKa low expectations are pessimistic behavior

Comment: @ebyrob in todays world there is one application which has answers to all questions i.e SEO no need to add tag specifically

Comment: @Srikanth I thought this site was supposed to provide "stand-alone" answers?  (Not ones that relied on another source for important content)  (Well, quoting is obviously OK, but should ideally include the important part without needing to click the reference link, or look up an IBN)

Comment: @DamienPirsy I've known about optimizing search engines since 1999 at least.  The acronym SEO sounds like SCO (which I *would* recognize unfortunately) and, to me, seems only useful to those with a pretty narrow focus.  Of course, narrow focus is typical of shorthands, acronyms, jargon and the like.  Often a wider audience deserves some clarification.